# How to reduce if statement redundancy

Tags: c#, if-statement, refactoring

I'm new to C# and making a simple grade calculator as a way to learn.
I have a 6 text boxes for a user to enter numbers and then a letter grade will show up beside it. It all works fine but it seems very redundant as I have 6 grades to convert and have 5 if statements for each just to show letters and then another one for average grade.

I assume there is a way to make this less redundant

```
if (grade1 >= 80)
{
    labelGrade1.Text = "A";
}
else if (grade1 >= 70 && grade1 <= 79)
{
    labelGrade1.Text = "B";
}

if (grade2 >= 80)
{
    labelGrade2.Text = "A";
}
else if (grade2 >= 70 && grade2 <= 79)
{
    labelGrade2.Text = "B";
}
```

Comment: Why are you checking `grade1 >= 80`  twice?

Comment: Copy/paste duplication?

Comment: Create a method that converts an int to a string and use that. `...Text = LetterFromGrade(grade)`. You can always take repeated code and put it in its own method (function).

Comment: that is more about programming pattern than C#, normally you would like to group one textbox and lable into a reusable component, inside the component you check the grade then display lable text accordingly, and reuse this component for all grades

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a method that encapsulates the duplicated code:

```
 string LetterFromGrade(int grade)
 {
     if (grade > 79) return "A";
     if (grade > 69) return "B";
     ...
 }
```

And then use that method everywhere.

```
 labelGrade1.Text = LetterFromGrade(grade1);
 labelGrade2.Text = LetterFromGrade(grade2);
 ...
```

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Comment: I like what you've done. The only thing I can see that someone might get twitchy about is that you've changed `>=80` to `>79` - which is identical as the type is `int` - but it may confuse the OP since they are a beginner.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is exactly what i was looking for. I have about 8 hours of C# coding under my belt so even this will require me to do some experimenting to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your code like this:

```
Action<int, Label> updateLabel = (value, label) =>
{
  if ( value >= 80 )
    label.Text = "A";
  else
  if ( value >= 70 )
    label.Text = "B";
};

updateLabel (grade1, labelGrade1);
updateLabel (grade2, labelGrade2);
```

Better smell.

You can of course create a class method instead of an local but if it is only used in a method, local is better as a class method allows other code to call it while this code is not intended for them.

[About delegate operator and anonymous methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/delegate-operator)

Answer (score -6):

### See Redundant Code below:

You cannot avoid some if statements. They are necessary.

[image: Shows redundant code]

### Further Details

I can only respond to the question asked. There was a lot of redundant code so I removed it! How am I to know that it is a typo on the part of the OP? Having said that, I wouldn't be too quick to remove 2-3 if statements. 5-6 if statements, then yes. Lastly, having reviewed the question again, Ian Mercer's answer looks good and not too complicated. But it assumes that the grading scale will be the same for each type of grade.

Comment: Clearly that was a typo in the question. This is not a helpful answer.

Comment: How do I write a good answer? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: [What is refactoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring)

Comment: Can't believe someone with 15k reps write this kind of answer.

Comment: Also, there's no need for the `value <= 79` condition, since the first `if` condition captures that set of values.